# Android, can't view file stored in external memory through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a function that downloads and extracts a zip file. 
Its extracted to the external storage in: ../Android/data/packagename/..

When I try the following intent to view a .mp4 video for example, its opened in a video player and says that it can't open the file. (not only .mp4 files)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Helper.getStorageDir(getActivity()) + "/" + mediaObject.getLinkOffline());

MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
Intent newIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(mediaObject.getLinkOffline().substring(mediaObject.getLinkOffline().lastIndexOf(".") + 1, mediaObject.getLinkOffline().length()));
newIntent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
newIntent.setFlags(newIntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
try {
    startActivity(newIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No handler for this type of file.", 4000).show();
}
```

However, when I go through a file explorer and open the same file there is no problem.

I have there read/write permissions in my manifest. But thats obviously not the problem since I can read write the file and can also check the the file exists. It just wont let an external app open the file through an intent from my app.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: when I debug and check the mime type for the mp4 file it is "video/mp4".

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: Testing on Nexus 5 with Android 5.1. @DavidWasser

Comment: There were major changes in 4.4 and again in 5.0 regarding app access to the external storage.  What surprises me is that your file explorer can access the files.